# make of Skeeter (PostgreSQL/ZeroMQ) failing on Mac OSX; problems with stdio.h?

Tags: c, macos, postgresql, makefile, failed-installation

I am interested in setting up the following library https://github.com/SpiderOak/skeeter to use PostgreSQL events with ZeroMQ. To build it, as per instructions, I perform a `make` with the provided `makefile`.

However, I am on Mac OS X and not Ubuntu, and I get the following errors:

```
cc -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Isrc -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3/include -DNDEBUG    -c -o src/bstrlib.o src/bstrlib.c
src/bstrlib.c:2762:12: error: expected parameter declarator
extern int vsnprintf (char *buf, size_t count, const char *format, va_list arg);
           ^
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:75:40: note: expanded from macro 'vsnprintf'
  __builtin___vsnprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), format, ap)
                                       ^
src/bstrlib.c:2762:12: error: expected ')'
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:75:40: note: expanded from macro 'vsnprintf'
  __builtin___vsnprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), format, ap)
                                       ^
src/bstrlib.c:2762:12: note: to match this '('
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:75:29: note: expanded from macro 'vsnprintf'
  __builtin___vsnprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), format, ap)
                            ^
src/bstrlib.c:2762:12: error: conflicting types for '__builtin___vsnprintf_chk'
extern int vsnprintf (char *buf, size_t count, const char *format, va_list arg);
           ^
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:75:3: note: expanded from macro 'vsnprintf'
  __builtin___vsnprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), format, ap)
  ^
src/bstrlib.c:2762:12: note: '__builtin___vsnprintf_chk' is a builtin with type 'int (char *, unsigned long, int, unsigned long, const char *, struct __va_list_tag *)'
/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:75:3: note: expanded from macro 'vsnprintf'
  __builtin___vsnprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), format, ap)
  ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [src/bstrlib.o] Error 1
```

`cc -v` output gives me:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Is this a problem because of a mismatch between OS X and Ubuntu? Will changing compiler get me anywhere? Is there something which is improperly configured? How do I move on with my debugging from here?

Comment: **INF:** your cited source quotes " *Skeeter is mainstream code, so **it should run on any reasonably current Linux**.* " so the problem ought be primarily discussed with them, ought be not?

Comment: Activity seems to have died down quite a lot (and I can't find alternate solutions) so I am resorting to other communities for help. I expect the code to work on Mac OS X, at the worst case with some minor variations and I appreciate any pointers in this regard.

Comment: **How about doing an MCVE-first** Step #0: Validate your intended package works as documented inside a published Ubuntu VM, where [ SpiderOak ] authors have published their promise their piece of code worked " *Our servers are currently running Ubuntu 10.4 LTS.* "? If this **PASS** / works as documented, the problem is in porting onto other O/S + kernel versions. If this **FAIL**s / does not work as doc'd, the problem is not in porting, but in the [ Skeeter ] package as-is. This is both a professional approach and fair to do MCVE-first ( before asking others to sponsor MCVE work ), isn't it?

Comment: Given that this technology in question is referenced by other technologies and is related to two other very popular ones, I took it for granted that it does work as claimed. I will confirm this but might take a bit more time than I wish due to limited resources -- and to be explicit, at the end of the day I really want a Mac OS X solution. I have to admit that I absolutely can't relate to your comments regarding the concept of MCVE; I have provided ample information to describe and reproduce this problem. What more information do you need to help get you up to speed?

Comment: I can confirm that the package compiles successfully on a Ubuntu 16 LTS system.